# How to exit a fragment and go back to previous activity or fragment from toolbar item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

How to exit a fragment and go back to previous activity or fragment from toolbar item?

I have tried calling getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(); from onOptionsItemSelected but it's not working.

Comment: did you try `finish()` method while navigating

Comment: I didn't.  You mean I should call getActivity().finish() after calling popBackStackImmediate()?

Comment: yes. try it and see.

Comment: That works!  Can you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

You can do this, If there are any fragments in the back stack, pop them else call `super.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: onBackPressed seems to me more for notifying than causing it to go back.  Is this a side effect?

Comment: Directly from the android documentation - "The default implementation of `onBackPressed()` simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want." So it is upto you, what you want to do in `onBackPressed()`. Calling finish() after popBackStackImmediate() won't help if there are more than one fragment in the back stack. Then calling finish() would simply kill the activity and all the fragments associated with it.

Comment: Thanks - what does onBackPressed in the case of multiple fragments associated with one activity?

Comment: If there are more than one fragment in the back stack calling the above `onBackPressed()` will navigate to the previous fragment. And if the back stack is empty calling `onBackPressed()` will simply kill the activity and move to the previous activity if there is any. Just like you wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                          .findFragmentById(R.id.container);

if(currentFragment instanceof YourFragment) {          
     this.getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction().remove(currentFragment).commit(); 
}
```

This will exit the fragment if its visible to user.

Comment: Does this code go in the activity? Or in the fragment? Does it matter what method it is in? Override onbackpressed or onclick if we have a button?

Comment: This code is in the activity. It doesn't matter what method it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getActivity().finish()` after calling `popBackStackImmediate()`

Comment: this just closes the entire app